# GRANT TO ROLE CREATE SESSION, SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, role, sql-grant

I need to grant  to role CREATE SESSION
SELECT (data from HR user EMPLOYEES table) privileges. I can grant these separately but is there any way to grant these privileges in one line?

```
grant select on hr.employees to role;

grant create session to role;
```

Comment: probably you cannot.. you may need to do this as separate DCL

Comment: Granting privileges to a role is something you will do only very occasionally, and quite possibly through a deployment script.  So what practical benefit might you gain from combining system and object privileges in one statement?